# How do you manage the unit test files in projects? do you add them in git?

Tags: php, git, unit-testing, phpunit

How do you manage your **PHPUnit** files in your projects?
Do you add it to your **git** repository or do you ignore them?
Do you use **@assert** tag in your **PHPdocs** codes?

Comment: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2

Comment: PS: curious - if you ignore and don't commit tests - how other team members (or even you) are supposed to work with them?

Comment: +zerkms thanks, and good point

Comment: Related: [Should I use PHPUnit in a staging/production environment](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11078572/632951)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Setup

I'm not using php currently, but I'm working with [python](http://python.org) [unit testing](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html) and [sphinx documentation](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) in git. We add our tests to git and even have certain requirements on test passing for pushing to the remote `devel` and `master` branches (`master` harder than `devel`). This assures a bit of code quality (test coverage should also be evaluated, but thats not implemented yet :)).

We have the [test files in a separate directory next to the top-level source directory](https://github.com/horazont/aioxmpp) in the directories where they belong to, prefixed with `test_`, so that the unit testing framework finds them automagically.

For documentation its similar, we just put the sphinx docs files into their own subdirectory (docs), which is in our case an independent git submodule, which might be changed in the future.

### Rationale

- We want to be able to track changes in the tests, as they should be rare. Frequent changes indicate immature code.
- Other team members need access to the tests, otherwise they're useless. If they change code in some places, they must be able to verify it doesn't break anything.
- Documentation belongs to the code. In case of python, the code directly contains the documentation. So we have to keep it both together, as the docs are generated from the code.
- Having the tests and the docs in the repository allows for automated testing and doc building on the remote server, which gives us instantaneous updated documentation and testing feedback. Also the implementation of “code quality” restrictions based on test results works that way (its actually more a reminder for people to run tests, as code quality cannot be checked with tests without looking at test coverage too). Refs are rejected by the git server if tests do not pass.

  We for example require that on `master`, all tests have to pass or be skipped (sadly, we need skipped, as some tests require OpenGL, which is not available on headless), while on `devel` its okay if tests just “behave like expected” (i.e. pass, skip or expected failure, no unexpected success, error or failure).

Comment: @Jonas, Your link https://github.com/pyuniverse/pyuniverse/tree/devel/Engine/Resources is broken

Comment: @Pacerier Thank you very much, I updated the link and the answer to reflect the current situation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, to keeping them in git. Other conventions I picked up by looking at projects, including phpunit itself. (A look at the doctrine2 example shows it seems to follow the same convention.)

I keep tests in a top-level `tests` directory. Under that I have meaningfully named subdirectories, usually following the main project directory structure. I have a `functional` subdirectory for tests that test multiple components together (where applicable).

I create `phpunit.xml.dist` telling it where to find the tests (and also immediately telling anyone looking at the source code that we use phpunit, and by looking at the xml file they can understand the convention too).

I don't use `@assert` or the skeleton generator. It feels like a toy feature; you do some typing in one place (your source file) to save some typing in another place (your unit test file). But then you'll expand on the tests in the unit test files (see my next paragraph), maybe even deleting some of the original asserts, and now the `@assert` entries in the original source file are out of date and misleading to anyone looking at just that code.

You have also lost a lot of power that you end up needing for real-world testing of real-world classes (simplistic BankAccount example, I'm looking at you). No `setUp()`/`tearDown()`. No instance variables. No support for all the other built-in assert functions, let alone custom ones. No `@depends` and `@dataProvider`.

One more reason against `@assert`, and for maintaining a separate `tests` directory tree: I like different people to write the tests and the actual code, where possible. When tests fail it sometimes points to a misunderstanding in the original project specs, by either your coder or your tester. When code and tests live close together it is tempting to change them at the same time. Especially late on a Friday afternoon when you have a date.

Comment: What do you mean by "`@assert` and skeleton generator"?

Comment: @Pacerier It is/was a wizard-like module to generate the skeleton of tests. Looks like it was moved out of core to an optional module as of phpunit 3.7: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12641670/841830  and currently found here: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-skeleton-generator

Answer (score 1):

We store our tests right with the code files, so developers see the tests to execute, and ensure they change the tests as required.  We simply add an extension of .test to the file.  This way, we can simply include the original file automatically in each test file, which may then be created with a template.  When we release the code, the build process deletes the .test files from all directories.

/application/src/ 
Foo.php 
Foo.php.test

/application/src/CLASS/ 
FOO_BAR.class 
FOO_BAR.class.test

`require_once(substr(__FILE__, 0, -5));  // strip '.test' extension`

Comment: Adding the .test extension actually makes it convenient, great tip.