# phpunit 3.7: what happened to the @assert annotation?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have phpunit 3.7

- In the documentation of [3.6, Appendix B,](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/appendixes.annotations.html) there is a `@assert`
  annotation, whereas
- In the documentation of [3.7, Appendix B,](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.annotations.html)
  there is **no** `@assert` annotation

The [official announcement](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/923-PHPUnit-3.7.html) mentions some new annotations (and the re-introduction of an old one previously deprecated), but it does not mention the removal of `@assert`. 
In the [changelog for 3.7.](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.7/ChangeLog.md), `@assert` is not to be found on the page

When I run my code on a class using the [code snippet](http://www.sitepoint.com/advanced-phpunit-testing-annotations-and-mocking/)

```
<?php
class MyMathClass
{
   /**
    * Add two given values together and return sum
    * @assert (1,2) == 3
    */
   public function addValues($a,$b)
   {
       return $a+$b;
   }
}
```

the output is

```
PHPUnit 3.7.1 by Sebastian Bergmann.



Time: 1 second, Memory: 4.25Mb

No tests executed!
```

with php 3.6.2

```
 phpunit MyMathClass.php
PHPUnit 3.6.12 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 2.75Mb

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

Comment: I thought the `@assert` annotation was only used to generate test skeletons, and I seem to recall that Sebastian was deprecating that feature. Clearly I'm mistaken about the first part but . . .

Comment: if you run phpunit 3.6 with `--debug` it prints `Starting test 'MyMathClassTest::testAddValues'.` it looks like this runs the skeleton generator on the fly. since its undocumented i feel its ok for the maintainer to give up this function.

Answer (score 5):

Answering my own question after doing some research. And thanks to the commenters for putting me on track.

The annotation is gone because it has been moved to the **optional** PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator package.

At this time, there are two confusing issues with this:

1. the removal of the @assert annotation from the phpunit "core"
2. the documentation being not updated properly

The changelog is imprecise. It says (wrongly):

> Removed deprecated --skeleton-class and --skeleton-test switches. The
>   functionality is now provided by the phpunit-*skel* command of the
>   PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator package.

A better way of saying this would sound more like this:

> Removed deprecated --skeleton-class and --skeleton-test switches. The
>   functionality is now provided by the optional phpunit-*skelgen*
>   command of the PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator package. 
>   Therefore, the @assert annotation has been removed from the phpunit core. 
>   It becomes available after installing PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator via PEAR.

Maybe I'll change this myself via github and notify the maintainers.

Comment: +1 and thanks for writing the answer! I've seen the question yesterday and came to the same conclusion while debugging it offline. I wasn't aware of this BC break (sorry!) and while we have a test for this is seems that test just wasn't run. I couldn't find the code that changed the behavior (due to time constraints) but If you'd be so nice to open a ticket with PHPUnit or sending a Pull Request for the docs (readme and/or manual) that would be really great :) - If not let me know and I'll see to it myself. --- Just to be clear: After installing skelgen it then works for you like before? :)